# API Manager 4.1, Management Console cant force Restart

Tags: wso2-api-manager

i have problem with cant force restart from management console login as admin. can anyone helping with me about this. i got log like this

```
`[2022-10-01 00:45:04,581]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2022-10-01 00:45:04,581]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 4.18.0-305.el8.x86_64, amd64
[2022-10-01 00:45:04,581]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_341-amd64/jre
[2022-10-01 00:45:04,581]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_341
[2022-10-01 00:45:04,581]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.341-b10,Oracle Corporation
[2022-10-01 00:45:04,582]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /opt/source/wso2_binary/wso2am-4.1.0
[2022-10-01 00:45:04,582]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /opt/source/wso2_binary/wso2am-4.1.0/tmp
[2022-10-01 00:45:04,582]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : abhimata, en-US, Asia/Jakarta
[2022-10-01 00:45:04,786]  INFO - DefaultCryptoProviderComponent 'CryptoService.Secret' property has not been set. 'org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider' won't be registered as an internal crypto provider. Please set the secret if the provider needs to be registered.
[2022-10-01 00:45:05,125]  INFO - KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2022-10-01 00:45:05,279]  INFO - TemplateDeployerServiceTrackerDS Successfully deployed the execution manager tracker service
[2022-10-01 00:45:06,716]  INFO - ServiceComponent Eventing Hub ServiceComponent is activated
[2022-10-01 00:45:07,431]  WARN - Digester Match [Server/Service/Engine/Host/Valve] failed to set property [maxDays] to []
[2022-10-01 00:45:08,095] ERROR - DefaultRealm nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:404) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:231) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:358) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:931) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:9083) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:320) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:262) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java:129) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:358) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
        ... 25 more
```

i expecting can force restart from management console or can with restart with command line from linux. please help me about this; thanks

Comment: Have you tried killing the process?

Comment: i was new about linux stuff. can helping me about how to check the process and kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can stop wso2server gracefully with ./wso2server.sh --stop. (./api-manager.sh --stop for latest versions)

In the management console(https://localhost:9443/carbon) also there is a shutdown button that you can use.

[image]

If you need to kill the process as you require right now, you can use in inbuilt Linux commands such as `ps` to locate the process and kill it.

Enter the command `ps ax | grep wso2`
This will list the set of processes started that has the text wso2. Unless you opened several apim instances, there will be one process that contains an ID. There, the first number refers to the process id.

Enter following command to gracefully shutdown the APIM.

`kill <process-id>`

You may force the shutdown by sending signal kill (-9) like follows if you need to.

`kill -9 <process-id>`

With ps again, if you can see there is a java process that sets the java home to <APIM_HOME>, additionally, you can kill it with
`kill -9 java`

Comment: thank you , this is really helping me alot. maybe last question i need know. when after we ps grep. what i need to kill. the process sh or java. because when i ps. there was alot PID appear. like  (70430 ?        S      0:00 sh /opt/source/wso2_binary/wso2am-4.1.0/bin/api-manager.sh) and (136680 ?        Sl     3:46 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_341-amd64/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/source/wso2_binary/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/logs/heap-dump.hprof)

Comment: you should kill both